# Firestore emulator and debugging security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-cli

After some effort I have now my Firestore emulator setup and my first tests written using mocha! Great.

I understand it is not possible to debug security rules step by step but is there a way to log information or state to the console, directly from the security rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is an undocumented function in security rules that lets you write debug values to the log when running on the local emulator.  Try the `debug()` function.  It takes a parameter with value to log, and returns that same value to continue evaluation of the expression.

```
match /users/{id} {
    allow read: if debug(id) == request.auth.uid;
}
```

Comment: This is working :)! Much better than nothing! Are there some other hidden secrets?

Comment: I also filled a feature request to be able to do something like debug("user id=", id) as otherwise just the value is logged without context